# jQuery function does not work after jquery.load() fetch the content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page and defined my java script functions in a custom.js file ( I'm using jQuery ).
I put JS file at end of body before `</body>` tag

My page have a div element like this:`<div id="userinfo"></div>`
when my page load, my JS file fetch an external page to that.

external page have a element like this`<div id="login"></div>`

in my JS file, I defined a function that when user clicked the `login` a modal window load an show the login form to the user.

but when i load the external page, my JS file does not work!!
it seems that can't find the element.

guide me Please!
:)

Some part of custom.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $('#userinfo').load('CustomerOptions.asp');

  (function() {
     $('#login').click(function(event){
         // something to do
     });
  })();

});
```

Comment: You said you put that in your <body></body> tag?  Also, do you have an example fiddle or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#userinfo').on('click','#login',function(){
    //Click logic here
});
$('#userinfo').load('CustomerOptions.asp');
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the code is trying to bind click event handler to #userinfo even before its available in the DOM (since the element is added to DOM via load asynch call).

Try this:

```
$('#userinfo').load('CustomerOptions.asp', function() {
     $('#login').click(function(event){
         // something to do
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It not works because you have assigned a event to #login before it is present in DOM. For cases like this you must use "live" events. Live events do not requires that the target element is present in DOM.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#userinfo').load('CustomerOptions.asp');

  $('#userinfo').on('click','#login',function(event){
     // something to do
  });
})();
```

EDIT: As pointed by @ManselUK, 'live' is deprecated, 'on' must be used.

Answer (score -1):

Or as an alternative you could use .live() instead of .click().

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: live is deprecated. `on` would be a better options.